# Cache action forever until invalidated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website in which there is a controller with an action that shows the restaurant profile. These profiles might get updated regularly or, they might not get updated for a long time. I was wondering if there is a trick which will somehow *invalidate* the action cache for a particular id. In that case I can use:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=int.MaxValue, VaryByParam="id")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Profile(string id)
```

and then, whenever the profile gets updated, I'd call something like `Cache.InvalidateFor("action", "controller", "id")`. The thing that I can do right now is to add the latest updated date and time as another parameter to the action. Something like:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=int.MaxValue, VaryByParam="id,lastChagned")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Profile(string id, DateTime lastChagned)
```

However, I wanted to avoid adding another parameter to the action which will make it look a little less neat.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Found the answer. Here's the code to remove an item from cache:

```
    public static void RemoveFromCache(string controller, string action)
    {
        var cacheManager = new OutputCacheManager();
        cacheManager.RemoveItem(controller, action);
    }

    public static void RemoveFromCache(string controller, string action, object parameters)
    {
        var cacheManager = new OutputCacheManager();
        cacheManager.RemoveItem(controller, action, parameters);
    }
```